# Using select statement with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables. One contains User and company relationship a show below

User_company

```
UserId    CompanyId
  1           2
  2           1
  3           1
  4           2
```

Another table holds user information

User

```
Id    Name    City
1     Peter    LA
2     Harry    SF
3     John     NY
4     Joe      CI
```

How do I make a statement which will give me All the users which are in company 1? Will something like

```
Select * from User where Id in (Select UserId from User_company where CompanyId = 1)
```

work?

Comment: There's lots of ways to do this.  ***Your way works***, but a join would generally be better (performance and scaling if lots of records in DB); especially if you want values from both tables.  Take a look at http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ for join help

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * from User
>
> left join User_company on User_company.UserId=User.Id

Comment: Missing where `companyID = 1` and why is a left join needed?

Comment: Sorry , I'm used to do a left join to keep the "User" data exists,
Thanks.

Comment: My answer. If you want your every User exists, you should add "left",but it may cause null if there are no values in UserId.If no "left", it would shows results which two table's UserId exists

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.* FROM User AS U LEFT JOIN 
   User_company AS UC ON U.Id = UC.UserId WHERE UC.CompanyId = 1
```

Comment: what do U and UC denote here?

Comment: Aliases for the tables.

Comment: I am using this in hibernate and it says unexpected token "on"

Comment: Command: "select c from com.ethor.model.Customer as c left join customer_restaurant as cr on c.id = cr.customer_id where cr.restaurant_id=:rId"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select u.* 
from User u
inner join User_company uc
on u.Id = uc.UserId
and uc.CompanyId = 1
```

BTW, what's wrong with the query you have posted? It will work as well fine. Just that it's a subquery and you better replace it with Join for performance.

```
Select * from User where Id in 
(Select UserId from User_company where CompanyId = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work...

```
SELECT *  works but can be sluggish over time as it may not scale well with more data.
FROM User 
WHERE Id in (Select UserId from User_company where CompanyId = 1)
```

So would this.. - best if you need data from both tables.

```
SELECT * 
FROM User U
INNER JOIN User_Company UC 
  ON U.ID = UC.UserID
WHERE UC.CompanyID = 1
```

As would this - Probably the fastest if you just need data from user table.

```
Select * from User U
where exists (Select * from User_Company UC where U.ID = UC.UserID and CompanyID = 1)
```

OUTER joins are only needed if you need all records from one table and only those that match in another.

As to which is the best above: it depends on existing indexes and other requirements.  Any of the above will return what's been asked for.